# Show password before hashing

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, passwords, blowfish

I am writing this code in cakePHP and I already have the authentication working just fine. The thing is that when I show the info of a user the password that is being shown is the hashed one, and this is useless. Is there a way to revert the hashing made by the blowfish hasher so I can see the actual password?

I'm using cakePHP 2.5 and my function to hash the passwords before saving is in my model like this:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And here is an example of what I get in the users/index view:

```
Id 5     
Name javier  
Password $2a$10$Awk8LMePPqiEPpavKk6xrulZKrbhNy5NVfkQSDF1E.PmgFtwYy60u
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, why not grabbing the password before you pass it to the model and beforeSave()? Before, it will not be modified/hashed.

Comment: If you need to display it to the user when you are hashing the password, set it to a variable for the view before you hash it and use that. After you've hashed it, there is no reason you should need to show the user their password, that's right - never. If you believe you do, you need to re-think the way your security system works. Once a password is hashed, it should stay that way forever.

Comment: Scowler is right, SSL has been defeated if you do show it. the purpose of it because it being a one way encryption scheme that has now thrown a plain text password out into the open. Plus hashing is meant for authentication, not encryption, therefore there is no reason ever to figure out the plain text version.

Comment: Yeah I'm dumb sorry guys, thanks for your answers all I had to do is implement a reset password option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know why passwords are hashed? This is thought as a security measure, if you save or display them besides the hash in clear text, the hashing becomes pointless, you don't have to hash them at all then. They're hashed in the case somebody gets access to the DB or the data in some way, without knowing the salt it's going to be pointless to try to decrypt the passwords.

Even sending plain text passwords via email is considered bad practice because most people don't use encrypted connections to their mailboxes and if somebody gets access to the mailbox, all the passwords are just waiting there for the attacker.

Send a token instead that is only valid for a limited amount of time and only let users change their password on your site, don't send plain text passwords around. And use SSL for login and password related actions.

If you need to tell users their password implement a reset method for admins that will trigger a password reset for the users or allow the admin to enter the password that then gets hashed.

Comment: Oh yes you are right I don't know why I was so obsessed with showing the current password, when all I had to do was add a reset password option. I'm sorry I asked such a dumb question, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hashing is intentionally one way, so you cannot revert the hash anyways.  This is to make sure that even if someone had the hashed passwords, and the salt, they still cannot easily figure out the password (though it does make them a lot closer to figuring it out.)  Encrypting is different from hashing, because encrypting can be undone through decrypting.